# multibyte identifiers list

Tags: php, javascript, html, multibyte

I was looking into multi-byte characters and how they are used but how many different identifiers/pasterns are used for different multi-bytes.

e.g: `&nbps;`,`&#nbsp;`,`U+0026`,`%20`

how many different identifiers such as `&`,`&#`,`u+` ,`%` etc are there ?

Im trying to look for inputs if they have words which are more than 255 characters long then its probably a multi-byte (hack attempt) and then I can check if word can be split has the multi-byte identifier then stop the hack attempt.

Comment: Search for HTML entities, that should explain most of these. Where did you find &#nbsp;? That is not a legal HTML entity. Maybe you mean something like &#60;.

Comment: This totally depends on what engine is going to parse the string. I don't think it makes sense to build a generic "hack detection" solution for this.

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. `&nbsp;` or `&#x0026` are called HTML/XML entities, `%20` are URI escape sequences. What do you call multibyte, what do you want to do?

Comment: @merijn i know about `&#nbsp;` but couldnt think of how that type of entity worked but none the less i knew it was something similar,

@benoit well what im trying to do is in the question lets say a input is something like `hello world` you have 2 words 5 letters each, but if you have `&nbps;&nbps;&nbps;&nbps;` no spaces there so its not a normal text its a special character then i can decide what to do with such special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%` format - a url-encoded value for embedding into URLS, e.g. %20 is a space (ascii 20)
`&nbsp;` - named character entity, a non-breaking space in this case
`U+0026` - a unicode character in hex notation, an `&` in this case
`&#...;` - a numbered character entity in decimal (base10) `&#38;` = &
`&#x...;` - a numbered character entity in hex (base 16): `&#x26;` = &

Comment: i know of these and i want to know of any other ones than those :)

Comment: Those are the ones I know of. The named entities are in the HTML specifications (and there's a lot of them). XML only supports about 6 directly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to avoid [homoglyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph)-based spoofing ? Does *identifier* means *username* here ?

If yes, and if your users use a latin alphabet, just allow only ascii letters and numbers:

```
$identifier = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]+#', '', $identifier);
```

Comment: identifier i meant `%` is the identifier of the url encoding